# How to round data in a list of lists to 2 decimal places?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the list:

```
 A= [[85.71428570204081, 86.6666666608889, 71.11111110953087, 66.66666666349205], [39.999999996, 67.99999999728, 86.36363635971074, 72.72727272396693], [87.49999999635418, 83.33333333101852, 64.86486486311178, 66.66666666349205], [73.07692307411241, 90.47619047188209]]
```

So my expected outcome is

```
A= [[85.71, 86.67, 71.11, 66.67], [40.00, 68.00, 86.36, 72.72], [87.50, 83.33, 64.86, 66.67], [73.08, 90.48]]
```

so when I apply this code:

```
 A=np.round(A,2)
```

It return me this error:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: above data id retrieve from dataframe and after combine become A

Comment: Your question does not match the title. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
In [114]: df = pd.DataFrame(A)

In [115]: df
Out[115]:
           0          1          2          3
0  85.714286  86.666667  71.111111  66.666667
1  40.000000  68.000000  86.363636  72.727273
2  87.500000  83.333333  64.864865  66.666667
3  73.076923  90.476190  64.285714  66.666667

In [116]: df.round(2)
Out[116]:
       0      1      2      3
0  85.71  86.67  71.11  66.67
1  40.00  68.00  86.36  72.73
2  87.50  83.33  64.86  66.67
3  73.08  90.48  64.29  66.67
```

Comment: but this one is not the dataframe for my output, even though I retrieve data A from dataframe

Comment: @ShiJieTio, you can do something like: `df.values.round(2)` instead of introducing `A` variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your have a list of lists and you have to supply a `numpy` array or matrix to the `np.round` method.

You can start by casting your list as and then use the method as you pretended to do

```
A= [[85.71428570204081, 86.6666666608889, 71.11111110953087, 66.66666666349205], [39.999999996, 67.99999999728, 86.36363635971074, 72.72727272396693], [87.49999999635418, 83.33333333101852, 64.86486486311178, 66.66666666349205], [73.07692307411241, 90.47619047188209]]
result =[]
for element in A:
    tmp = np.round(np.asarray(element),2)
    result.append(tmp.tolist())
result

[[85.71, 86.67, 71.11, 66.67],
 [40.0, 68.0, 86.36, 72.73],
 [87.5, 83.33, 64.86, 66.67],
 [73.08, 90.48]]
```

Comment: Then your code and what you showed in the question are different.

Comment: I already approve editing for the question, sorry I just new to python so hopefully can get some hints here

Comment: I extended the code in my answer to make explicit what I do and works as expected. If it's not working on your side, then `A` is something different.

Comment: Hi I can get the answer by following your step, but the length of the array may be different, that why I cant able run the code, I just now only notice I my lists maybe like following:
A= [[85.71428570204081, 66.66666666349205], [39.999999996, 67.99999999728, 86.36363635971074, 72.72727272396693]]

so I notice if the length is different than it will pop up the array as I post, if like this any solution recommended?

Comment: Probably not the most elegant or efficient but don't have more time to clean it now.